# Prometheus rules - check for ocp configuration changes

Tags: openshift, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm looking to write a prometheus(in openshift) rule to check configurations(e.g deployment, deploymentconfigs) on openshift.

May I know is this possible? or is there a sample I can use and modify it?

Thanks

Comment: Please write more details about what you want to check. Count number of deployments?

Comment: example: if i `oc edit deployment abcd`, change something inside, then `:wq`, can prometheus pickup the changes?

Comment: Thanks, and what do you want to do after getting alert from Prometheus? If you want to know when a deployment change, event log might be helpful.

Comment: then alertmanager should send email. you mean event log from deployment?

Comment: `kube_deployment_metadata_generation` could be the metrics what you want. But I couldn't come up with any idea how to send alert with a prometheus rule expression. 
So, I think that the event from deployment is a better way.